# Xcode - ask user to accept request from other user

Tags: xcode, parse-platform, tracker

I was having trouble wording the title, sorry.

Basically, I want to know the best practice when asking permissions from one user to another. An example would be those family tracker apps, where one user requests to follow another, and said user has to accept that request so the first user can follow their locations.

I am using Parse if that makes a difference. Thanks!

Comment: You will need to refer sample apps for Parse such as AnyPic:https://parse.com/tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For achieving this with Parse, I would recommend creating a class in Parse called `Following` which will have two `User` class pointers - `fromUser` and `toUser`. The class could also have a bool called `allowed`.

When a user requests to follow someone else, a new `Following` object is created and `allowed` defaults to false. Only when the `toUser` accepts to be followed, then you can update `allowed` to be true.

In terms of how to prompt the `toUser` if they accept the follower, [you could use a simple UIAlertController](http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/).

Also, I highly recommend [checking out the Parse Anypic tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/anypic).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.